# 拡張for文でClassCastExceptionが発生します。

Tags: spring-boot, java8

拡張for文の箇所でClassCastExceptionが発生します。エラーが出ないようにStudentオブジェクトのIdをそれぞれコンソールに出力するにはどう修正したらよろしいでしょうか。お願いいたします。

```
■Testクラス
@Controller    
public class Test {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false,defaultValue="World") String     name    ,Model model){


        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Student> aiu = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9292/student?userId=0000    2", List.class);

        for(Student a : aiu){
            System.out.println(a.getId());

        }
        return "login";
    }
}

■Studentクラス
public class Student {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String score;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}

■StudentControllerクラス
@RestController
public class StudentController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method=RequestMethod.GET)

    public List<Student> get(@RequestParam String userId) {

        List<Student> a = new ArrayList<Student>();

        Student aa = new Student();
        aa.setId("0001");
        aa.setName("安藤");
        aa.setScore("30");

        Student ab = new Student();
        ab.setId("0002");
        ab.setName("田中");
        ab.setScore("48");

        a.add(aa);
        a.add(ab);

        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: RestTemplateのソースを貼ってください。`restTemplate.getForObject`があやしいです。

Answer (score 1):

下記のコードだと、Listの型指定はしていないので、
要素はObjectになってしまい、ClassCastExceptionが発生するのだと思います。

```
List<Student> aiu = restTemplate.getForObject("...", List.class);
```

以下のように、Student型の配列で受け取るようにすれば、
ClassCastExceptionは発生しなくなるかと思います。

```
ResponseEntity<Student[]> responseEntity = 
    restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Student[].class);
Student[] aiu = responseEntity.getBody();
```